# How to use Javascript in .NET MAUI Blazor App Hybrid

Tags: c#, .net, maui, maui-blazor

when ever i try to put javascript link in .NET MAUI Blazor App Hybrid it says "Script tags should not be placed inside components because they cannot be updated dynamically."

Please help

i want to use javascript in .NET MUAI Blazor App Hybrid

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: There are two similar issues in the MAUI-Blazor Github page: [.NET Core 3.0 Blazor Server side <script> tag](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/13917) and [Add compiler error if there's a <script> element inside a component](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/16218). You can refer to it.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to use JavaScript using the modular approach.

Let's assume you have file hello.js which contain functions like below:

```js
export function helloWorld (name) {
    console.log("Hello "+ name);
}
```

Try creating an interop for your JS file like:

```cs
public class Interop : IDisposable
{
    private readonly string _filePath;
    protected readonly IJSRuntime _jsRuntime;
    private Task<IJSObjectReference> _module;
    
    public Interop(IJSRuntime jsRuntime)
    {
        _filePath = filePath;
        _jsRuntime = jsRuntime;
    }
    
   public Task<IJSObjectReference> Module => _module ??= _jsRuntime.InvokeAsync<IJSObjectReference>("import", "./hello.js").AsTask();
    
    //create a method to call function from the JS file
    public async void SayHelloWorld(string name)
    {
        var module = await Module;
        await module.InvokeVoidAsync("helloWorld", name);
    }
    
    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (_module is not null)
        {
            ((IDisposable)_module).Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

then use the js function like:

```cs
new Interop(JSRuntime).SayHelloWorld("Adam");
```

Comment: javascript have to many funcation should i do this for each?

Comment: If you've a set of functions to accomplish a task then you can use them inside a single export function as per you logic and then call that export function via interop.

Comment: any github sample?

Comment: I cannot say it an exact sample but here's a link to some code which will show that how I use to work with that thing.
https://github.com/Tech-Flurry/TechFlurryUtils/tree/master/TechFlurry.Utils.MetronicComponents

Comment: can you check what i'm doing wrong? https://github.com/Essa999khan/BOIAPP

Comment: Can you please mention the specific files on which you are working in this shared repo?

Comment: https://github.com/Essa999khan/BOIAPP/blob/master/BOIAPP/wwwroot/index.html